# Interpolating between two points on Stiefel manifold

Tags: matrices, smooth-manifolds

I'm looking for a formula to interpolate between two given matrices from the Stiefel manifold (orthogonal n by k matrices).

I do not know the tangent direction, I only know the start and end points so I'm not sure if formulas requiring the tangent vector to the Stiefel manifold can be used.

So far, I have looked at the paper by Edelman et al and Huper's "Rolling Stiefel manifolds".

Thanks.

Comment: I am not entirely certain about the meaning of "interpolation" in this context. Are you looking for a curve connecting the two given points?

Comment: You mean a geodesic?

Comment: Yes.  I am looking for a curve connecting two given orthonormal matrices, where all points on this curve are also orthonormal matrices. I think the easiest way is to linearly interpolate, between these two matrices, and then do a QR factorization of this intermediate matrix, and take the Q factor.

Comment: @ Poloni  Yes, a geodesic.  But I don't know the tangent direction.  Only the start and end.